# What does System.in.read actually return?

Tags: java, java-io

What does :

```
System.in.read()
```

return ? The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29)  says :

***Returns:
the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the stream is reached.***

But for example if I enter : `10` I get back `49` . Why is that ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`49` is the ASCII value of the char `1`. It is the value of the first byte.

The *stream* of bytes that is produced when you enter <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> on your console or terminal contains the three bytes `{49,48,10}` (on my Mac, may end with 10,12 or 12 instead of 10, depending on your System).

So the output of the simple snippet

```
int b = System.in.read();
while (b != -1) {
    System.out.println(b);
    b = System.in.read();
}
```

after entering a 10 and hitting enter, is (on my machine)

```
49
48
10
```

Comment: Because `10` is two bytes. A byte representing the character 1, followed by a byte representing the character `0`.

Comment: @saplingPro The thing to realize is that when you enter "10", you're not entering the _number_ 10, but rather _text_ which happens to be "10" but could have been "foo" or even "☃ is melting!". What `System.in` sees are the bytes of this _text_ stream. For ascii and extended ascii (so, not my little snowman up there), check out http://www.ascii-code.com

Answer (score 5):

`System.in.read()` reads just **one byte**.

*49* is the **Unicode** point value for *1*.

Try to print:

`System.out.println((char)49);`

This will help you to understand it more.

Answer (score 3):

When you enter `10`, it is not read as an integer but as a String or, more precisely here, an array of bytes.

49 is the ASCII code for the character `1`.