# What is the difference between Scanner.next() and System.in.read()?

Tags: java, input

I see that many people use java.lang.Scanner.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = sc.nextInt();
```

But, I mentioned in some book the code:

```
class Guess {
  public static void main(String args[])
  throws java.io.IOException {
    char ch, answer = 'K';
    System.out.println("I'm thinking of a letter between A and Z.");
    System.out.print("Can you guess it: ");
    ch = (char) System.in.read(); // read a char from the keyboard
    if(ch == answer) System.out.println("** Right **");
  }
}
```

I just wanted to know whats the difference between using the first example and using System.in.read();

Thank you! Also do you need throws java.io.IOException when you want to add user input in your program? What does it do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708071/system-in-read-method Check this link. You may find something helpful

Answer (score 2):

This reads an integer

```
int i = sc.nextInt();
```

e.g. if you type

```
1234
```

it will return the `int` value `1234`

This read a character for each key you pressed

```
char ch = (char) System.in.read();
char ch2 = (char) System.in.read();
char ch3 = (char) System.in.read();
char ch4 = (char) System.in.read();
char ch4 = (char) System.in.read();
```

and if you type

```
1234<enter>
```

it will have

```
ch == '1'; // == 49
ch2 == '2'; // == 50
ch3 == '3'; // == 51
ch4 == '4'; // == 52
ch5 == '\n'; // == 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your guess would have to be a character, inputting a character using the first example would throw `java.util.InputMismatchException`, and basically scanners suck in [reading single characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2597939), with that said even the second solution has its own flaws and wont work try the input `Katastrophe`, and for the IOException, the method  `System.in.read()` throws it, so you either catch it or throw it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = sc.nextInt();
```

In above case Here we create object of scanner (i.e. sc) and `sc.nextInt()` get the input from user so if user enters an integer value suppose '3' then this value is stored to variable a;

In second case `ch = (char) System.in.read();` here `System.in.read()` read a character for key you pressed and store that into variable ch. You can also use scanner to read character or string like this `sc.next();` and if you have to read string with spaces (e.g. "hello there !!!") then you can use `sc.nextLine()`

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner.next() and the System.in.read() are just several approaches to get data to a program from an "outer world" (file system, console, etc).

 The System.in.read() reads only single character when the java.lang.Scanner is able to read not only lone symbol, but a whole line.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

In the example above "sc" uses System.in.read() in its methods.

 The main difference between your examples is that in the first example Scanner invokes System.in.read() itself, but in the last one a programmer invokes it explicitly.

 Java I/O is an immensely big topic. You'd better to delve deeper to understand all conceptions. There are some packages which contain IO features: java.io, java.nio

Most IO methods throw the IOException. This one is a checked exception, so you must either catch it within a try-catch block or add to a method signature after 'throws' keyword.