# Unexpected output using static block in Java

Tags: java, output, static-block

I am trying to execute this code but its giving me random values everytime:

Output:

[image: Output]

Code:

```
public class Temp  {
    static int x;
    static {
        try {
            x = System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}


class TempA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Temp.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by random values? Can you give an example? Are you typing something into your keyboard while running the program?

Comment: As random [as this](https://xkcd.com/221/)?

Comment: Usually `System.in.read()` returns the next byte currently stored in `System.in`. This object usually is connected to your standard input, the console for example. So if your typing something into the keyboard it will get stored there. So I would assume that if you type in `5` it will also print `5`.

Comment: @Zabuza Suppose I type 23 as input, it gives me 50 as output. Yes, I am typing something on my keyboard while running the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values aren't random, they're:

> [...] the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()

This means if you type `a` and hit `Enter` you'll get `97`.

If you're looking for content of what was typed (and not the raw byte value) you'll need to make some changes... The easiest way it to use the `Scanner` class.  Here's how you get a numerical value:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temp  {
    static int x;
    static {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        x = sc.nextInt();
    }
}


class TempA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Temp.x);
    }
}
```

See also [System.in.read() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708071/).

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is returnung the `ASCII` value of the first digit/character of your input.

Comment: Well, not ASCII and not value in general, but the next byte of whatever the stream is supplying. Given that the `System.in` stream is typically being feed from the console/shell, it is usually typed text. There is no text but encoded text. The shell is using whatever character encoding it is using, and that's typically UTF-8, or CP437 or similar, not ASCII. Go `locale` or `chcp` to find yours.