# Java input return incorrect values

Tags: java

I use this [official example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang/Systeminread.htm) to receive input from the user and then print it:

```
import java.io.IOException;

    public class MainClass {
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        int inChar;
        System.out.println("Enter a Character:");
        try {
          inChar = System.in.read();
          System.out.print("You entered ");
          System.out.println(inChar);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
          System.out.println("Error reading from user");
        }
      }
    }
```

The problem, It always returns incorrect values. For example, When enter 10 it returns 49 while I expect to return 10!
What is the reason for this issue and how could I solve it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446689/what-is-the-use-of-system-in-read-in-java There are several links in the comments that can help.  But I am curious why you wouldn't use the Scanner class.

Comment: This example has nothing official. If it was official, the URL would be at oracle.com. The example sucks. It's wrong. It doesn't read a char, but a byte. Here's the official Java IO tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: System.in.read(); read one character (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--). "1" is 49 in decimal and "0" is no read.

Answer (score 2):

This returns the `int` value of a character, if you want to print the character cast it to `char`:

```
System.out.println((char) inChar);
```

This will only print the value of the first character that was input because System.in.read() only reads the first byte.

To read a whole line you could use a `Scanner`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write something:");
        // read input
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("You entered ");
        System.out.println(line);
      }
}
```

Comment: It also return incorrect it returns 1 for 10

Comment: @sємsєм because it only reads 1 byte like i said. I edited my answer to include a solution to read a whole line.

Comment: @sємsєм: learn to read the comments and answers. And learn basic things kike what a character is. A character could be '1', 'a', 'T' or '0'. It can't be '10'. '10' is two characters: '1' and '0'.

Comment: @user432 `Scanner cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: @sємsєм add `import java.util.Scanner;` at the top.

Comment: @sємsєм: programming can't be learnt in a few minutes by copy and pasting code without understanding anything about it. It takes years. Start by reading a book or tutorial about the basics of Java.

Answer (score 0):

> System.in.read reads only first byte from input stream

So if you enter

> 123

the first character is 1.So its corresponding ASCII is 49

If we enter

> 254

the first character is 2.So its corresponding ASCII is 50

Edit:This is explained also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273449/what-does-system-in-read-actually-return)

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet.

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader brInput = new BufferedReader(isr);
String strInput = brInput.readLine();
System.out.println("You wrote "+strInput);
```