# Why is my program stopping after the System.in.read() function?

Tags: java, function, class

```
package myfirstclass;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyFirstClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        Car RedCar;
        RedCar = new Car();

        RedCar.carColor = "red";
        RedCar.milesPerGallon = 25;
        RedCar.numDoors = 2;

        Car BlueCar = new Car();
        BlueCar.carColor = "blue";
        BlueCar.milesPerGallon = 50;
        BlueCar.numDoors = 4;

        System.out.println("Choose a car...");
        int read = System.in.read();


        if(read == 1){
            System.out.println("Hello, and your car is...");

            System.out.println("Red!");

        }



    }
}
```

After I input a number, such as 1, it just says "Build Successful!", why is this? And how can I fix it to make sure it reads my input and follows the "if" statement correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest printing out the value of `read` to see what you get. Hint: it's not 1.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273449/what-does-system-in-read-actually-return

Comment: You've asked almost exactly the same question before here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298551/why-does-this-do-while-loop-not-produce-the-right-output.  What is it about the answers there that you are still unclear on?  If you can explain that - maybe we can help you.

Comment: All 3 of your questions on this site relate to System.in.read() - I think that you have a misunderstanding of what it does.  The question now has two answers that give you an idea of what to look at.  My personal opinion is that the suggestion to use a Scanner object for console based input is the best idea.

Comment: Yes, I would agree with you, J Richard. I figured it out, and will be using Scanner object from now on, thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.in.read() reads exactly one byte. In your example, the variable read will hold the value 49, not 1.

Use a Scanner instead:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = scanner.nextInt();
```

Useful links:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()

Answer (score 1):

`System.in.read()` does not do what you think. It reads *one byte* from input and returns the *integer value* of it. If you type "1", `System.in.read()` returns 0x31, or 49. Not 1.

Unfortunately, what you want is way too complicated in Java.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
if (Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()) == 1) {
    // do something
}
```

The first line creates an inane object that Java requires to read lines. The second line reads one line from the input using `in.readLine()`, converts it to an integer with `Integer.parseInt`, and then compares it to 1.

Comment: `Unfortunately, what you want is way too complicated in Java` You've just solved in a "complicated" way. JamesB for example has a much easier way (also easier to read for new ones). But still a possible way.

Comment: Upvote for suggesting an alternative to `Scanner`.