# System.in.read using my char value as an int?

Tags: java

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String []args)
    throws IOException{
        char ch;
        int xh;
        ch=(char)System.in.read();
        xh=System.in.read();
        System.out.println(ch);
        System.out.println(xh);
    }
}
```

If it puts an input of 1 in `for`, the `char` value in the `System.in.read();`
 will use that value for the `xh`.

For instance, if I put 1 in it, it will automatically give 1, 10 and will not give me an option to input my `int` value.

Why is that? Also, I know I can use a scanner instead, but I don't want to.

Comment: Consider `int i = 'a';`, does that help?

Comment: no , also I dont really follow ur logic, you setting an int to a char value? System.in.read(); already by default returns an int value

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273449/what-does-system-in-read-actually-return  `10` is the `CR` after the `1` in your input stream.

Comment: And not a `char`. I don't follow your question. You call `read` twice. What are you trying to do?

Comment: System.in.read(); is basically the same as the scanner, hence, it create a line for input. I called it twice , because in the first input I want the user to put a char in and the second line I want them to put an int in