# System.in.read() is misbehaving when trying to enter integer value

Tags: java, input

> I'm trying to enter integer value through System.in.read().
>   But when I'm reading the value it is giving different output 49 for 1, 50 for 2 & so on `int e=(int)System.in.read();
>           System.out.print("\n"+e);`

Comment: The reason for that is that the `System.in.read()` reads a character, not an integer. 
So when you cast the char '1' to an int, you get the ASCII value of the char '1', which is 49.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15273449/4472840

Answer (score 2):

Because character `1` (i.e. `char ch = '1'`) has ASCII code `49` (i.e. `int code = '1'` is `49`).

```
System.out.println((int)'1'); // 49
```

To fix your examle, just substract code for `0`:

```
int e = System.in.read() - '0';
System.out.println(e); // 1
```

Comment: Better yet, don't use `read()`.

Comment: @Andreas I agree, `Scanner` is much better, but this is not a scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading char with function

> System.in.read()

You can see the use of System.in.read() [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446689/what-is-the-use-of-system-in-read). Also please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506077/how-to-read-integer-value-from-the-standard-input-in-java) how to read a value from user.

Comment: No *"cast to int"*, since [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--) returns an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the correction @Andreas.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have mentioned, `System.in.read()` reads in a single character in the form of an `int`, or `-1` if there is no input to read in. This means that characters read in with `System.in.read()` will be `int`s representing ASCII values of the read characters.

To read in an integer from `System.in` it might be easier to use a `Scanner`:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int e = s.nextInt();
System.out.print("\n"+e);
s.close();
```

or, if you wish to stick to using `System.in.read()`, you can use `Integer.parseInt(String)` to obtain an integer off of the character input from `System.in.read()`:

```
int e = Integer.parseInt("" + (char) System.in.read());
System.out.print("\n"+e);
```

`Integer.parseInt(String)` will throw a `NumberFormatException` you can catch if the input is not a number.